# MySQl 5.7 installation failed on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

```
Configuring mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.11-0ubuntu6) … 
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5). 
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server 
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue. 
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11 
dpkg: error with
   mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
```

apt-get remove return the same result.

This error come in with upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Answer (score 14):

It was exactly same for me: runlevel warnings and mysql_upgrade error.

I guess it was because I disabled mysql service, enabling it fixes the problem:

`sudo systemctl enable mysql`

Comment: Here's the bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1605948

Comment: save my ass, baga

Answer (score 2):

I've just encountered this problem, there's a bug report that is quite similar here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1584287

In my case I had the `mysql.service` set to disabled and the `mysql_upgrade` script seemed incapable of starting the server in this case. I enabled the service (didn't need to start it) and re-ran the upgrade. After that worked I stopped the service and disabled it again.

I'm not sure what else might cause this, but if someone encounters this with the service disabled, just enable it for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Manualy remove all file of MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Seems mysql-server is now replaced with mariadb

Installing maridb-server fixed the issue.

sudo apt-get install mariadb-server

Note:- You won't get your databases. Reset mysql password using command mysql_secure_installation

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could solve the problem by changing `apparmor` (on kubuntu 16.04 using plasma).
I took a look at `journalctl -xe` as suggested by the installation error message:

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

In there I found apparmor DENIED messages:

```
AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/home/system/var/log/mysql/error.log" pid=32610 comm="mysqld" request
```

In deed, the base directory `/home/system/...` exists, but access is not allowed by `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`.

So adding the following lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` solved my problem:

```
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.

# Allow log file access
  /home/system/var/log/mysql.err rw,
  /home/system/var/log/mysql.log rw,
  /home/system/var/log/mysql/ r,
  /home/system/var/log/mysql/** rw,
```

Don't forget to restart apparmor, and restart mysql installation (e.g. `apt-get install --reinstall mysql-common mysql-server` or whatever is your way to install it.)

I don't know at all why (and since when) the directory `/home/system` exists and why mysql points in there. But some day a hopefully figure out ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me, found solution - [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1571865)

1. sudo update-alternatives --remove my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.migrated
2. sudo service mysql start

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution [here](http://mokoetle.blogspot.com.ng/2015/05/failed-to-restart-mysqlservice-unit.html)

1. Remove all of mysql's files: 
   `rm -r /var/lib/mysql*`
2. Install mysql self database: 
   `mysql_install_db -u mysql` 
   (might not work for newer systems, but don't worry)
3. Enable the service for systemd: `systemctl unmask mysql.service`
4. Then start the mysql `service service mysql start`

Comment: Beware! This `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql ` also removes ALL user databases !

Comment: Yes it does. IT was stated there in the #1 statement. It's because of `incompatible` newer mysql files that the service fails to start.